# Error when clicking on button: NameError: name is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

I have a small window with Tkinter that I use to insert, update and delete fields in a database. The window consists of the Treeview ranking, the textboxes in which to insert the text and the buttons: Insert, Update, Delete.

PROBLEM: when I click on the "Update" or "Delete" buttons, the following error appears (error same as both, ie selected_item to Update, and selected_item to Delete)

```
NameError: name 'selected_item' is not defined
```

Here is the code I use. It's a bit long, but it's quite simple and intuitive (I remove some parts useful for operation, in order to lengthen the code and improve readability):

```
# GUI
frame_search = Frame(app)
frame_search.grid(row=0, column=0)
barrasopra=Frame(app, width=2200, height=47, background="#d9d9d9")
barrasopra.place(x=1, y=1)
barradue=Frame(app, width=2200, height=47, background="#78c030")
barradue.place(x=1, y=47)


#CLASS DATABASE

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
        self.cur.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS routers (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Relaz_Campionato integer, Relaz_Giornata integer, Data numeric, Ora numeric, Relaz_Sq1 integer, Relaz_Sq2 integer, Risultato_Sq1 integer, Risultato_Sq2 integer)")
        self.conn.commit()

    def fetch(self, hostname=''):
        self.cur.execute(
            "SELECT * FROM routers WHERE hostname LIKE ?", ('%'+hostname+'%',))
        rows = self.cur.fetchall()
        return rows

    def fetch2(self, query):
        self.cur.execute(query)
        rows = self.cur.fetchall()
        return rows

    def insert(self, Relaz_Campionato, Relaz_Giornata, Data, Ora, Relaz_Sq1, Relaz_Sq2, Risultato_Sq1, Risultato_Sq2):
        self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO ARCHIVIO_Risultati VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                         (Relaz_Campionato, Relaz_Giornata, Data, Ora, Relaz_Sq1, Relaz_Sq2, Risultato_Sq1, Risultato_Sq2))
        self.conn.commit()

    def remove(self, id):
        self.cur.execute("DELETE FROM routers WHERE id=?", (id,))
        self.conn.commit()

    def update(self, id, Relaz_Campionato, Relaz_Giornata, Data, Ora, Relaz_Sq1, Relaz_Sq2, Risultato_Sq1, Risultato_Sq2):
        self.cur.execute("UPDATE ARCHIVIO_Risultati SET Relaz_Campionato = ?, Relaz_Giornata = ?, Data = ?, Ora = ?, Relaz_Sq1 = ?, Relaz_Sq2 = ?, Risultato_Sq1 = ?, Risultato_Sq2 = ? WHERE id = ?",
                         (Relaz_Campionato, Relaz_Giornata, Data, Ora, Relaz_Sq1, Relaz_Sq2, Risultato_Sq1, Risultato_Sq2, id))
        self.conn.commit()

    def __del__(self):
        self.conn.close()


conn= sqlite3.connect('/home/db.db')
cur= conn.cursor()
db= Database('/home/db.db')


def select_router(event):
    try:
        global selected_item
        index = router_tree_view.selection()[0]
        selected_item = router_tree_view.item(index)['values']


        Relaz_Campionato_entry.delete(0, END)
        Relaz_Campionato_entry.insert(END, selected_item[1])

        Relaz_Giornata_entry.delete(0, END)
        Relaz_Giornata_entry.insert(END, selected_item[2])
        #######################################################
        Data_entry.delete(0, END)
        Data_entry.insert(END, selected_item[3])
        
        Ora_entry.delete(0, END)
        Ora_entry.insert(END, selected_item[4])
        
        Relaz_Sq1_entry.delete(0, END)
        Relaz_Sq1_entry.insert(END, selected_item[5])
        
        Relaz_Sq2_entry.delete(0, END)
        Relaz_Sq2_entry.insert(END, selected_item[6])

        Risultato_Sq1_entry.delete(0, END)
        Risultato_Sq1_entry.insert(END, selected_item[7])

        Risultato_Sq2_entry.delete(0, END)
        Risultato_Sq2_entry.insert(END, selected_item[8])

       
    except IndexError:
        pass

def remove_router():
    db.remove(selected_item[0])
    clear_text()
    populate_list()

def update_router():
    db.update(selected_item[0], Relaz_Campionato_text.get(), Relaz_Giornata_text.get(), Data_text.get(), Ora_text.get(), Relaz_Sq1_text.get(),
                Relaz_Sq2_text.get(), Risultato_Sq1_text.get(), Risultato_Sq2_text.get())  
    populate_list()

def clear_text():
    Data_entry.delete(0, END)
    Ora_entry.delete(0, END)
    Relaz_Sq1_entry.delete(0, END)
    Relaz_Sq2_entry.delete(0, END)
    Risultato_Sq1_entry.delete(0, END)    
    Risultato_Sq2_entry.delete(0, END)                           

def execute_query():
    query = query_search.get()
    populate_list2(query)


# FIELDS DATABASE
# Data
Data_text = StringVar()
Data_label = Label(app, text='Data', font=('bold', 11), bg='#f0f0f0', foreground='black')
Data_label.place(x=6, y=380)

Data_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=Data_text)
Data_entry.place(x=180, y=380)

# Ora
Ora_text = StringVar()
Ora_label = Label(app, text='Ora', font=('bold', 11), bg='#f0f0f0', foreground='black')
Ora_label.place(x=6, y=420)
Ora_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=Ora_text)
Ora_entry.place(x=180, y=418)

and others that I don't write 



#FRAME RISULTATI, CON VISUALIZZAZIONE AD ALBERO

frame_router = Frame(app, bg='#d9d9d9')
frame_router.place(x=6, y=105)

columns = ['id', 'Data', 'Ora', 'Sq1', 'Sq2', 'Risultat1', 'Risultato2']
router_tree_view = Treeview(frame_router, columns=columns, show="headings")
router_tree_view.column("id", width=30)
for col in columns[1:]:
    
    router_tree_view.column(col, width=170)
    router_tree_view.heading(col, text=col)
    
router_tree_view.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', select_router)
router_tree_view.pack(side="left", fill="y")
scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame_router, orient='vertical')
scrollbar.configure(command=router_tree_view.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
router_tree_view.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

#COLORE TABELLA
style = ttk.Style(app)
style.configure("Treeview",
                background="white",
                foreground="#000000",
                rowheight=25,
                fieldbackground="white")
style.map('Treeview', background=[('selected', '#99d260')])


#RECALL BUTTONS 
def populate_list(hostname=''):
    for i in router_tree_view.get_children():
        router_tree_view.delete(i)
    for row in db.fetch(hostname):
        router_tree_view.insert('', 'end', values=row)

def populate_list2(query='select * from routers'):
    for i in router_tree_view.get_children():
        router_tree_view.delete(i)
    for row in db.fetch2(query):
        router_tree_view.insert('', 'end', values=row)

def add_router():
 if Relaz_Campionato_text.get() == '' or Relaz_Giornata_text.get() == '' or Data_text.get() == '' or Ora_text.get() == '' or Relaz_Sq1_text.get() == '' or Relaz_Sq2_text.get() == '' or Risultato_Sq1_text.get() =='' or Risultato_Sq2_text.get()=='':
     messagebox.showerror('Required Fields', 'Please include all fields')
     return
 db.insert(Relaz_Campionato_text.get(), Relaz_Giornata_text.get(), Data_text.get(), Ora_text.get(), Relaz_Sq1_text.get(), Relaz_Sq2_text.get(), Risultato_Sq1_text.get(), Risultato_Sq2_text.get())
 clear_text()
 populate_list()


#Populate data
populate_list()



#BUTTON
frame_btns = Frame(app, bg='#d9d9d9')
frame_btns.place(y=2)

add_btn = Button(frame_btns, text='Aggiungi nuovo', width=12, bg='#78c030', command=add_router)
add_btn.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=7, padx=7)

remove_btn = Button(frame_btns, text='Rimuovi',
                    width=12, bg='#78c030', command=remove_router)
remove_btn.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=7)

update_btn = Button(frame_btns, text='Aggiorna',
                    width=12, bg='#78c030', command=update_router)
update_btn.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=7)

clear_btn = Button(frame_btns, text='Pulisci',
                   width=12, bg='#78c030', command=clear_text)
clear_btn.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=7)
```

Comment: The error means exactly what it says. Often, this means the code is executing in an order where the code that defines it doesn't run until after the code that uses it. A couple of `print` statements should be able to prove that. Call `print` when you set it, and again when you use it, and see what order the print statements appear in the console.

Comment: @BryanOakley I think I understand, but maybe not. I am new to Python. Could you answer me with an answer where you show me how to please please? I'm sorry for the trouble. Thanks

Comment: you need to make sure that select_router will get called before you press the update or delete button. Else it wont be defined resulting in the error. Another solution would be to say in the beginning: ```selected_item = ""``` and check in the delete or update router function ```if selected_item == ""```. If thats the case then just stop executing the function (with ```return```) or ask the user to select a router so that selected_item will have a value different from "".

Comment: @sputnick567  I tried to call select_router before hitting the button, but this gave me other problems (I copied the code from the web, code that was already a bit flawed). Could I illustrate, in the answer, the solution you are talking about please? How could I write the code with if selected_item = "" and return? Thanks (sorry, I'm new to Python)

Comment: @BryanOakley I got this code from the web. It was a little flawed and gave me other errors. I tried to fix it and at least now the window starts up. Except that the error I speak of above appears to me. I know it is an order problem, I tried to fix it but I can't. Could I please help me? I can not. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Typically this is because of case sensitive, mis-spelling, or just forgetting to even define it in the first place. If it is none of the above problem, you need check if you defined selected_item before being used. If it is defined before calling, then check if there is anything that deletes it, such as del selected_item, you can always print out the variable to see what it is.